# Android Providing Up Navigation issue

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I wanna create app which is working proper activities. I have created notification.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyService.this)
    .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
Intent intent = ErrorStateActivity_.intent(MyService.this)
    .flags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
    .errorCodeExtra(ErrorStateActivity.NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION_CODE)
    .get();
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    MyService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
mNotificationManager.notify(NotificationConstants.INTERNET_CONNECTION_ERROR, notification);
```

Here is manifest

```
<activity
   android:name=".activity.MainActivity_"
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
   android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
<activity
   android:name=".activity.ErrorStateActivity_"
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
   android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity_">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
       android:value=".activity.MainActivity_"/>
</activity>
```

And here is My ErrorStateActivity part

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home: {
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
            // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                            // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
            // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
        return true;
       }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

}

When notification apperas and tap it, ErrorStateActivity opens and click up back button it backs MainActivity. No problem.!!!! But when app kill app from recent app and do above proccess it doesn`t back to MainActivity. Please help me! Thank in advance.

Comment: either of ur buttons doesn't work correctly? The android's back button and the apps home button?

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? It's not working for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

@sam_k Try to test it

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    handleBack();
}

private void handleBack() {
    Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
    if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
        // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
        // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                        // Navigate up to the closest parent
                .startActivities();
    } else {
        // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
        // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
    }
    ErrorStateActivity.this.finish();
}
```